# Decrease function calls for ngShow - AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, ng-show

I want to show a `<div>` based on the value of a function in the scope.

Like this:

```
<div ng-show="myFunction(id)">{{myFunction(id)}}</div>
```

But, I have to make the function call twice. Can we make it any more optimized?

Comment: What do you mean call it twice, and why do you want to optimize it?

Comment: I do not want to call the function twice. That's more processing power, right?

Comment: Oh no no no no, NEVER optimize, unless it's necessary. This is called premature optimization, and it's a very alluring trap.

Comment: Okay. I was just worrying if more function calls mean more processing and slower performance. `myFunction()` actually goes through a big list for working. So, I wanted to avoid second call.

Comment: 1) You can use Chrome's profiler to check the performance, if it's not acceptable, try to optimize it. 2) Oh I get it. Wait. :P

Comment: I need 1 more thing before I answer, how does the argument `id` change? Do you change it through JS?

Comment: Just so you know, what you want, is probably to create [a service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) that returns the value of that function.

Comment: I am actually using a service. The actual function is something like this:
`DataService.findPrice('item.id')`

This `<div>` is inside an `ng-repeat` directive.

Comment: May you provide more context? I sense you are writing you application wrong....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You obviously mean that the calculation of `myFunction(id)` happens twice, once to evaluate if the ng-show is true, and once to show its value in the div.

You can easily avoid that, by caching its value.

`$scope.functionResult = myFunction(id);`

Every time that id changes, you can trigger an event, and recalculate `myFunction` and update `$scope.functionResult`